# Correct params for ElasticSearch with PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am attempting to make a Google like search using ElasticSearch and PHP. I have been reading a ElasticSearch book and I think I was to use simple_query_string query type that can take the keywords (or phrase) from a search box and try to find some of all of the terms entered.

I am using the PHP ElasticSearch library in my project and after connecting to my server I am trying to pass a $client->search($params) to my search to return a result.

I have this as my params array

```
$params =
            [
                'index' => 'letsmeetup',
                'type' => 'person',
                'body' =>
                    [
                       'query' =>
                            [
                                'simple_query_string' =>
                                [
                                    'query' => $keywords,
                                    'fields' => [
                                        "first_name","last_name","bio","username","email_address","interests","skills"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                    ]
            ];
```

I used a phrase like 'People who love php' and I get results. I tried 'real time web' (which is in my bio) as I get the correct result.

Problem is when I try 'Er', knowing there is a first_name of "Erin", or 'Neo', which I have "neo4j" in my bio, it's returning no results. Do I have the params array correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wildcards for these kind of queries

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [ "first_name","last_name","bio","username","email_address","interests","skills"],
      "query": "Er*"
    }
  }
}
```

This will match "Erin", "Eric", "Error" and so on.
You can find more information about Query String Syntax and wildcards here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Should I replace the simple_query_string or can I add the wildcard as a fall back or in addition too?

Comment: You could append wildcard to your query but you could get few more results, As a caution, please do not use *word as ES will have to search through the entire index

Comment: So what would be the best config to get a full statement search plus partial word results such as Er or Neo?